# How can I get RGB value of pixel at specified point on the camera screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to get color value of specified point on the camera screen (without capturing) in terms of RGB.

I had following code snippet, but it gives value of view's background color not the picture on camera screen.

```
CGPoint point=CGPointMake(100,200);
unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];

CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

NSLog(@"pixel: R=%d G=%d B=%d Alpha=%d", pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[3]);
```

Comment: There is an API to do a full screen capture, try that. May work I don't really know for sure.

Comment: Thanks David H,

I know that API, But my question was... I want to get RGB Value for specified point on that camera view.

Comment: No, I understood your question. If you know the offset of the camera view, and the offset to the pixel, then you can compute what the offset is into the window (screen). You can even use UIView methods to do this conversion for you. If the snapshot does grab the camera view (and I don't know if it does), then the offset to the pixel you want is a simple mathematical operation.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want to do this in real time (rather than using a screen capture, which you specifically say you *don't* want):

You first need to be capturing the video buffer **[as outlined by Apple here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html)**.

Then you can do what you like with the `CMSampleBufferRef`. Apple's sample app makes a `UIImage`, but you can simply copy it across into an `unsigned char` pointer (via a `CVImageBufferRef` or `CVPixelBufferRef`) and then pull the BGRA value of the pixel in question, something like this (untested code: example is for the pixel at 100x,200y):

```
int x = 100;
int y = 200;
CVPixelBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
tempAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
int bufferSize = bytesPerRow * height;
uint8_t *myPixelBuf = malloc(bufferSize);
memmove(myPixelBuf, tempAddress, bufferSize);
tempAddress = nil;
// remember it's BGRA data
int b = myPixelBuf[(x*4)+(y*bytesPerRow)];
int g = myPixelBuf[((x*4)+(y*bytesPerRow))+1];
int r = myPixelBuf[((x*4)+(y*bytesPerRow))+2];
free(myPixelBuf);
NSLog(@"r:%i g:%i b:%i",r,g,b);
```

This gets the position relative to the pixels of the video feed itself, which may not be what you want: if you want the position of the pixel as displayed on iPhone's display, you may need to scale this.

Comment: I stumbled on this great explanation. Thank you. Can you elaborate on the "A" of the BGRA. I have seen a lot of code trying to normalize for the A before analyzing the BGR. Can you explain on why the normalizing process before using the BGR data. Thanks

Comment: It's the alpha. Which, in the case of a video frame buffer such as this, is always 100% and so can be ignored (it's just that iOS operates in a 32-bit color space even when it doesn't really need to).