# video encoding and conversion using ffmpeg

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, xuggler

I have to create a website of vod (films), and the problem is that i have to convert my video to different formats to be supported by all browsers (mp4,ogg and webm), the problem is that when someone will add a film with a size >1Gb, the conversion to the other formats will take a lot of time (I tested ffmpeg and xuggler api on java ), is there any other library faster than ffmpeg or an onother approach to manage my large videos?
Thank you

Comment: There is no free lunch. Video encoding is a CPU intensive task (especially when you want to go for "high-quality"). My gut feeling would be: don't expect that you can gain more than 5 or max 10% in performance by using other products. In other words: you might consider restricting the file sizes allowed for your users; you might consider providing more / better hardware; but in the end: video encoding and conversion is expensive. No chance to dramatically reduce cost by software only (all IMHO).

Comment: Another approach is to distribute encoding jobs to multiple machines.

Comment: can I use hadoop (mapreduce/hdfs) to accelerate video conversion?

Comment: I think @EddyG is correct, but it might be of interest to see if leveraging the HW on your server can get you any useful speed gain. I'm not sure what gains can be expected from HW acceleration with ffmpeg, and I'd imagine it may even differ for different videos, but there is some useful H.364 related discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23669968/334402